# adobe molehill android setting

Tags: molehill

Using Flash Builder 4.6 & SDK 4.6
Away3d and Starling Interoperation
device - samsung galuxy s3

debugging on device, its run well.
install exported apk on the device, its just white background.

[app name]_app.xml file setting is

```
<renderMode>direct</renderMode>

    <!-- Whether or not to pan when a soft keyboard is raised or lowered (either "pan" or "none").  Optional.  Defaults "pan." -->
    <!-- <softKeyboardBehavior></softKeyboardBehavior> -->
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

just use latest Air sdk.

http://www.flashdeveloper.co/post/10985842021/overlay-adobe-air-32-in-flash-builder-46